# How do you determine which physical device is 'under' a given mount point?

Tags: mount

Is there a command that tells you the device name (ie. "/dev/sda1"), when you give it a mount point (ie. "/home")?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 9.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df -k /home
```

and

```
mount
```

Answer (score 4):

`df`, `mount`, or just `cat /etc/fstab`.

If the actual physical device is hidden behind software RAID (eg, you see /dev/md), then `cat /proc/mdstat` will uncover that layer.

And if there's a blanket of LVM (eg, you see something like /dev/LogVol00), use `pvdisplay`.

Comment: when you use cat though, doesn't it just tell you what's supposed to be mounted, not what actually is? If you had a typo in /etc/fstab, the entry would be there, but the device might not actually be mounted due to the error.

Comment: For /etc/fstab, you're exactly correct.